# Dúvida sobre Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework-2

Desenvolvi uma aplicação na *versão 2.5 da ZF2*, e me veio uma dúvida caso não atualizar para *versão ZF3* minha aplicação poderá ocorrer algum problema?

Comment: Primeiramente, está pegunta é muito ampla e pode ter várias respostas. Mas na verdade, não vai acontecer nenhum problema diretamente. O que pode acontecer é vc precisar de alguma funcionalidade nova do ZF3, ou mesmo algum conserto. Ou ainda quiser utilizar uma lib que dependa das versões mais novas do ZF. Caso vc não atualize não poderá utiliza-los.

Answer (score 0):

Com certeza ocorrerá problemas, atualizei o meu do 2.5 para o 2.7 e apresentou erro no servicemanager, na verdade seria um aviso de que a forma como eu estava usando estaria obsoleto e que no ZF3 não iria funcionar.

Me desculpe mas não tenho maiores detalhes, mas faça uma busca e com certeza terá maiores detalhes.

Comment: Na verdade ele perguntou o contrário. Se **não** atualizar poderá ocorrer algum problema?

Comment: Verdade, eu interpretei o inverso. ;) @ViníciusFagundes